# Function for table mathematical calculation

Tags: r

```
SNP Ind_1   Ind_2   Ind_3   Ind_4   Ind_5
SNP1     0       0       1       2       0
SNP2     2       0       1       2       1
SNP3     2       0       0       2       1
SNP4     1       1       2       2       2
```

I want to do these following steps

Step 1. Add all SNP row values for Ind_1 and then subtract it by 10 and create a new rowname with score. Ex: Ind_1 = 0 + 2 + 2.....  = 5 and then 10-5=5

Step 2 Repeat the same analysis for Ind_2 to Ind_5`

There are more than 1000 Ind rows and more than 50 SNP columns. Thus a function for that will be a great help. Actual values are not 0, 1 or 2. They are like 1.5, 0.05, 0.001., means between 0 and 2. I just provided this table to look easier

Results should look like this

```
SNP Ind_1   Ind_2   Ind_3   Ind_4   Ind_5
SNP1      0       0      1       2       0
SNP2      2       0      1       2       0
SNP3      2       0      0       2       0
SNP4      1       1      2       2       0
SNP5      0       0      0       2       0
Score     5       9      6       0      10
```

`

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering what you were up to!  Have fun!  Seriously, this is not a free code-writing service, you need to have at least tried something yourself...  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a simple one-liner:

```
# Your sample data
df <- read.table(text = 
    "SNP    Ind_1   Ind_2   Ind_3   Ind_4   Ind_5
     SNP1     0       0       1       2       0
     SNP2     2       0       1       2       1
     SNP3     2       0       0       2       1
     SNP4     1       1       2       2       2", header = T, row.names = 1);


df <- rbind.data.frame(df, score = 10 - colSums(df));
df;
#      Ind_1 Ind_2 Ind_3 Ind_4 Ind_5
#SNP1      0     0     1     2     0
#SNP2      2     0     1     2     1
#SNP3      2     0     0     2     1
#SNP4      1     1     2     2     2
#score     5     9     6     2     6
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using base R. `dt2` is the final output.

```
result <- as.data.frame(t(10 - colSums(dt[, 2:ncol(dt)])))
result$SNP <- "Score"
dt2 <- rbind(dt, result)
dt2

#     SNP Ind_1 Ind_2 Ind_3 Ind_4 Ind_5
# 1  SNP1     0     0     1     2     0
# 2  SNP2     2     0     1     2     1
# 3  SNP3     2     0     0     2     1
# 4  SNP4     1     1     2     2     2
# 5 Score     5     9     6     2     6
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "SNP Ind_1   Ind_2   Ind_3   Ind_4   Ind_5
SNP1     0       0       1       2       0
                 SNP2     2       0       1       2       1
                 SNP3     2       0       0       2       1
                 SNP4     1       1       2       2       2",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```